# Google Wonder Wheel / Google Plus Circles Animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to create an interface like Google Wonder Wheel and Google Plus Circles ( The circle in which you can add your friend.) for my project using jQuery. Any idea how to get started ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circlehack!
http://www.circlehack.com/

and for the source:
https://github.com/voloko/facebook-circles/tree/master/src/view

Not jquery, but using UKI javascript library

Answer (score 0):

I would start with jQuery UI's draggable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
Then add a little CSS / hover type stuff.  Is that what you were looking for or you want something more specific?